# A simple way to calculate outs on a poker game in java

Tags: java, statistics, calculator, poker, evaluator

I need to calculate the odds on a poker hand by Java. This is for a school project I don't have much time and I can't find any good and simple method or algorithm.

Comment: In order to count outs you would need to be able to evaluate a 5, 6, or 7 card hand and determine whether it is a straight, full house, one pair, etc. Therefore no simple algorithm exists

Answer (score 0):

I would start with some of the answers in this thread: [Poker Hands in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205949/poker-hands-in-java)

Once you can evaluate poker hands, counting outs should be easy.